# Remove event from HTML tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);
const htmlTag = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]; 
function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    let events = ["click"];         
    if(message.txt == 'start') {        
        // Attach all events to the window
        events.forEach((eventName) => {
          htmlTag.addEventListener(eventName, consoles);
        });
    }
    else {
        events.forEach((eventName) => {
          htmlTag.removeEventListener(eventName, consoles);
        });     
    }
    function consoles() {
        console.log('test');
    }
};
```

This function attach the events I mentioned in **events[]** but I cann't detech it in else function. When I pass stop txt, it still displays console log. Consider for if condition, message.txt = 'start' and for else, message.txt = 'stop'. Please suggest me what I am missing here?

Comment: Move `function consoles()` block outside of gotMessage.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh god.. it worked.. but how??

Comment: Each time your gotMessage runs it creates a new function for `consoles` with a new internal "address".

Comment: Oh silly me..!!! please post this as your answer so I can accept it. Thanks a bunch. you saved my day.

Comment: I think there should be a much better canonical answer with more info because this is an old problem.